# how to monitor/sniff local DNS lookups to the windows local DNS? (on XP, Vista, Win7)

Tags: c#, .net, dns

Is there a way in .NET (for a WPF application running on XP, Vista, or Windows 7) to monitor/sniff DNS lookups that the application is making to local DNS?

For example, is there a log file for a windows local DNS cache somewhere?

(Background - parsing network packets doesn't seem to work as a DNS lookup may not have to be issued outside of the PC if it is already cached in the Windows DNS)

Comment: Nothing in the native API, nothing in the WMI provider.

Comment: admittedly obvious, but if you're ok with disabling the DNSCache service, you could then use the network sniffing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, checking tcpview+perfmon /res, it appears that dnscache listens on 'localhost' (for both ipv4 and ipv6 on my win7) on UDP port 5355, and since netmon can capture localhost traffic (most sniffers can't AFAIK), you should be able to use the NMAPI (look at Microsoft Network Monitor 3\api\NetmonAPI.cs after you install it) to monitor that traffic.

- NetMon: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en

VRTA and NMExperts (IIRC) site on top of the managed interface if you want places to look for existing consumers for sample code:

- VRTA: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=119f3477-dced-41e3-a0e7-d8b5cae893a3&displaylang=en
- NMExperts: http://nmexperts.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks James - so re "most sniffers can't AFAIK" do you happened to know whether WinPCap can or not?  (if I'm using this so far)  WinPCap gets used in Wireshark too I believe.

Comment: BTW - There's not a more basic way of monitoring the local DNS cache, such as a log file?

Comment: Re: log - I couldn't find any other monitoring approach, unfortunately, although that doesn't mean it doesn't exist :)  The definitive answer would likely be from either asking on one of the Windows forums or opening a ticket with Microsoft support.

Comment: Re: sniffers - in my past experience (over a year ago at this point) with winpcap/wireshark, it couldn't see localhost traffic (not its fault - localhost traffic doesn't get routed through the normal network stack - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/localhost-http-debugging-with-fiddler.html).  AFAIK netmon had to do specific work to support localhost traffic, but i never really dug that much into it